# Magnetics part with and without auto-transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, ethernet, layout, magnetics

I have 2 magnetics part.

One magnetics is [this](https://www.haloelectronics.com/pdf/discrete-single-1gbaset.pdf) (Circuit A configuration magnetics) & the other magnetics is [this](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/pulse-electronics/HX5008NL/1036960)

When I use the Halo part, the ethernet link is not up. But when I just replace the Halo part with the Pulse electronics part, the link is up without any issues.

Then, I found that the Pulse magnetics part has an auto-transformer portion inside it.

My question is, is the auto-transformer portion helping with the ethernet linking-up?
Or, it might be because of some other issue with the PCB?

Comment: There are thirty-two parts in the first datasheet. Please try to be at least a little specific.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks. Edited the question.